# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging indicated for social activity messages

Tags: firebase, vue.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, social-media

I need to handle social activity events in my web app application developed using Vue JS framework and Firebase.

I want to show to the user “Facebook like” notifications when some activity happen in the application, for example:

“John liked your post”.

Is Firebase Cloud Messaging useful for this scenario? Or do I have to develop some custom solution from scratch?

If Firebase Cloud Messaging do the job, is it possible to send messages directly from user web client?

Comment: FCM could be useful, yes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, this messages are cached automatically by Firebase?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. That sounds like a complete different question than the one you started with.

Comment: What i mean is: If the user in my web application is offline, the messages sent by FIrebase Cloud Messaging are lost?

Comment: I'm lost.  What you're asking now doesn't seem to have much to do with your original question.  I suggest editing the question to better explain the issue.

Comment: For messages i mean “activity events” as the Likes to a user post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to send messages directly from the web client.  FCM is intended to be used via a secure backend where your code runs to send messages.  The reason a backend is needed is to prevent your private server key from being exposed to the world, which can cause security issues in your app.

You will have to arrange on your backend to determine when events occur that should generate messages, and use the Firebase Admin SDK to send those message, or work with the REST API directly.